# Firing TRIAC / AC Light DIMMER module

Tags: microcontroller, motor-controller, esp32, induction-motor, dimmer

I am currently testing the AC light dimmer with a blower fan output that has a specification of 220V 0.45A. When the trigger angle is set to 0, why does the output of the AC light dimmer allow a voltage of 135V with a current of 0.5A, which exceeds the specification? Why is it possible to allow such voltage and current at that angle, and why doesn't the blower rotate due to the effect of the voltage and current leakage? Meanwhile, at a trigger angle of 10, only a voltage and current of 47/0.013 are allowed, and at a trigger angle of 20, only 61/0.022 are allowed

Comment: Why are you using a *light* dimmer on a *motor*. A light dimmer will not work well with the inductive load of a motor.

Comment: my video with light and fan https://www.youtube.com/shorts/3gH2Eg5rLE0

Comment: I just want to see the reaction when controlling with a dimmer module, is there an explanation of what happens in this case?